# Event-B Proof Obligations

Tags: operating-system, event-b, formalize

I have a problem in Event-B to discharge proof obligations. In my work,
I want to formalize the specification of memory protection requirements to check the consistency between them. In order to do that, I used Event-B Context to formalize the system's structure and used Event-B Machine to describe the requirements. Each requirement is described in both Invariant and Event. Event-B will check each pair requirement to find the inconsistency. 
However, it cannot prove that two requirements are consistent:
1: "**Read** access from **NonTrusted** to the **data_section** of **other OS_Apps** is **may_prevent**" 
2: "***Read and Write*** access from an ***OS_App*** to its ***own data_section*** are ***shall_permit***"

This is my work. Firstly, in the context file, I describe the structure of the system and the access control:
**1. System's Structure:**
We have 2 types of OS_Application: **Trusted** and **NonTrusted**.
2 types of OS_Objects: **Tasks** and **ISRs**. 
2 types of ISRs: **Category_1** and **Category_2**. 
Each OS_Object belongs to one OS_App: ***ContainerOf ∈ OS_Obj → OS_App*** 
Each OS_App has a code section: ***AppCode ∈ OS_App → CodeSection*** 
Memory has 2 parts: **DataSection** and **Stack** 
OS_App and OS_Obj ***may*** have DataSection:

- ***AppData ∈ OS_App ⇸ DataSecs***
- ***ObjData ∈ OS_Obj ⇸ DataSecs***

OS_Obj has their own Stack: ***ObjStack ∈ OS_Obj → Stacks***

**2. Access Control:** 
The Access is from ***Subjects*** to ***Objects***: 
**Subjects** include: **OS_App** and **OS_Obj** 
**Objects** include: **Code_Section**, and ***Memory*** 
In the below code, **line 20** describes: "The stack for these objects, by definition, belongs only to the owner object and there is therefore no need to share stack data between objects, even if those objects belong to the same OS-Application."

***line 21*** describes: "Code  sections  are  either  private  to  an  OS-Application  or  can  be  shared between  all  OS-Applications" 
***line 22, 23*** describe: "OS-Applications  can  have  private  data  sections  and  Tasks/ISRs  can  have private  data  sections." 
***line 24*** describes: "OS-Application's private data sections are ***shared by all*** Tasks/ISRs belonging to that OS-Application. "

By the analysis, I define the context as follows:

```
1:  OS_Obj ⊆ Subjects   
2:  OS_App ⊆ Subjects ∖ OS_Obj
3:  Tasks ⊆ OS_Obj
4:  ISRs ⊆ OS_Obj∖Tasks
5:  Category_1_ISRs ⊆ ISRs
6:  Category_2_ISRs = ISRs ∖ Category_1_ISRs
7:  Trusted_OS ⊆ OS_App
8:  NonTrusted_OS = OS_App ∖ Trusted_OS
9:  CodeSection ⊆ Objects
10: Memory ⊆ Objects ∖ CodeSection
11: DataSecs ⊆ Memory
12: Stacks ⊆ Memory ∖ DataSecs
13: partition(actions_set, {initact}, {read}, {write}, {execute})
14: partition(status_set, {initStt}, {shall_prevent}, {shall_permit}, {may_prevent}, {may_permit})
15: ObjData ∈ OS_Obj ⇸ DataSecs
16: ObjStack ∈ OS_Obj → Stacks
17: AppCode ∈ OS_App → CodeSection
18: AppData ∈ OS_App ⇸ DataSecs
19: ContainerOf ∈ OS_Obj → OS_App 
20: ∀obj1,obj2 · (obj1 ∈ OS_Obj ∧ obj2 ∈ OS_Obj ∧ (obj1 ≠ obj2) ⇒ (ObjStack(obj1) ≠ ObjStack(obj2)))
21: ∀app1, app2 · (app1 ∈ OS_App ∧ app2 ∈ OS_App ∧ app1 ≠ app2) ⇒ AppCode(app1) = AppCode(app2)
22: ∀app1, app2 · (app1 ∈ dom(AppData) ∧ app2 ∈ dom(AppData) ∧ app1 ≠ app2) ⇒ AppData(app1) ≠ AppData(app2)
23: ∀ obj1, obj2 · (obj1 ∈ dom(ObjData) ∧ obj2 ∈ dom(ObjData) ∧ obj1 ≠ obj2) ⇒ ObjData(obj1) ≠ ObjData(obj2)
24: ∀ obj, app · (app ∈ dom(AppData) ∧ obj ∈ OS_Obj ∧ obj ∈ dom(ObjData) ∧ app ≠ ContainerOf(obj)) ⇒ ObjData(obj) ≠ AppData(app)
25: ∀ app, app1, app2 · (app ∈ dom(AppData) ∧ app2 ∈ dom(AppData) ∧ app1 ∈ NonTrusted_OS ∧ app = app1 ∧ app1 ≠ app2 ∧ AppData(app) = AppData(app2)) ⇒ ⊥
```

Secondly, In the Machine file, I describe:

```
prf_1:  ∀app1, app2 · ((action = read) ∧ app1 ∈ NonTrusted_OS ∧ app2 ∈ dom(AppData) 
∧ app1 ≠ app2 ∧ src = app1 ∧ dst = AppData(app2) 
∧ status ≠ initStt) ⇒ status = may_prevent 

prf_2: ∀app · ((action = read ∨ action = write) ∧ app ∈ dom(AppData) 
∧ src = app ∧ dst = AppData(app) ∧ status ≠ initStt) ⇒ status = shall_permit
```

And two events: [Two events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCtTT.png) 
After that, the event-B generates Proof Obligations and try to prove the consistency. However, that two requirements are inconsistent as follows:
[undischarged Proof Obligation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkcTi.png) 
In the Goal box: It cannot prove that: 
`A = (¬(app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app ∧ AppData(app2)=AppData(app)))` is true. 
However, in requirement no.2, we have: `app1 ≠ app2` 
=>  `app ≠ app2 (because app1=app)`
=> `AppData(app2) ≠ AppData(app)`
Therefore, `(app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app ∧ AppData(app2)=AppData(app)` = FALSE 
then A = `(¬(app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app ∧ AppData(app2)=AppData(app)))` = TRUE.

Could you give me some hints or comment, please?

Comment: I think this question belongs to the [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit guessing here since your given model is quite long and it's not obvious what is going wrong or what should be proven. You might improve your question by removing the not used stuff.

You want to prove

```
¬(app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app ∧ AppData(app2)=AppData(app))
```

(I do not understand the part `A=`, the right side is a predicate, not an expression.)

Let's apply a case distinction on `app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app`:

- If it is false, then the whole predicate is trivially true.
- If it is true, we have it as an additional hypothesis and it remains to prove (*):

  ```
  ¬(AppData(app2)=AppData(app1))
  ```

From your screenshot, we can see that `app1 ≠ app2`, so to instantiate axiom 22 you still need `app2∈dom(AppData)` to get the needed result `AppData(app2)≠AppData(app1)`. It is not visible in your screenshot, but might be there somewhere.

(*): Maybe you can achieve this by introducing an hypothesis `¬(AppData(app2)=AppData(app1))` (by "ah"). Afterwards you can use this and the hypothesis from the case distinction above to prove your goal.

*Just a comment*: The axioms 22 and 23 can be completely replaced by defining the functions `AppData` and `ObjData` as injective, e.g. `ObjData ∈ OS_Obj -+>> DataSecs`. This would not only make the spec more readable, I think the provers can handle those better than quantified statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I help one more question. I am still confused with the term "interactive proof". When we use "interactive proof", do we prove by hand writing or use Rodin platform to add hypothesis?

Comment: An interactive proof is done within the Rodin platform. It is usually a mixture of manual steps and starting the automatic prover when the complicated parts are broken down. In this example it would probably be entering app∈dom(AppData) ∧ app1=app and pressing dc, then trying to solve the sub-goals by the automatic prover, if that does not help, entering the hypothesis and pressing ah. So in total this interaction in Rodin is the interactive proof. The automatic proof is just when the automatic solver succeeds directly at the start. To my knowledge there is no other "external" proof script.